# collection_select values and names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around a collection_select that I'm trying to do.  Some background: I have a nested model where I have an layout and each layout can have a set number of images.  As part of the input, the user is allowed to decide what image goes in what order.  This is dictated by the `layout_placement` value of the image.  This currently works, the layout_placement is a plain text field where the user can input etc.

```
<%= f.fields_for :images do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.file_field :image %> 
  <%= builder.label :layout_placement %> <%= builder.text_field :layout_placement, :size => 3%>
  <br /><br />
<% end %>
```

What I need though is a drop-down in place of the plain text field that will allow me to limit the value of the `layout_placement` selected - this is based on the number of spaces available (each layout is different and has anywhere from 2 to 5 image slots).

I already have a field in the layout called `image_slots` that gives me the number of available image slots for the layout being used. So I want to make my available options a range from 1 to the number of image slots. I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<%= builder.collection_select :layout_placement, 1..@layout.image_slots, ???, ??? %>
```

And I get stuck on what to pass for the `:id` and `:name` methods.  I've tried going simpler and just using the `select_tag` but I  get stumped in a different area in that, since it's a nested model the `:object#method` settings goes wrong.

Any help in making either option work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you don't really need to use the collection_select since you want the text and value of your options to be the same thing (ie: 1..@layout.image_slots). Try this

```
<%= builder.select :layout_placement, 1..@layout.image_slots %>
```

In the case where your image_slots might return `nil` just make sure you handle it properly

```
<%= builder.select :layout_placement, 1..(@layout.image_slots || 1) %>
```

To validate the placement values are uniq, add this to your Image model

```
validates_uniqueness_of :layout_placement, :scope => :layout_id
```

Comment: Thanks for including the possibility of image_slots being nil.  Is there a validation that I can do to ensure the image slots selected are unique?  As in if '1' is selected in 2 selects then it flashes a validation?

Comment: Edited my answer to include the validation piece.